# How separate (string, int and float) each item of a list in python

Tags: python, database, list, split, items

I'm new in python so I have a list as example

```
['wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CG - 0.990 ', 'wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CE1 - 0.916 ', 'wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CD2 - 0.963 ', 'wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C GLN 33 CD - 1.000 ']
```

I want to split it like this:

```
wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CG - 0.990
wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CE1 - 0.916
wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CD2 - 0.963
wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C GLN 33 CD - 1.000
```

my script is like this:

```
filename = 'output.txt'
with open(filename) as f:
    for i in f:
         print i
```

I have used print "\n".join(i) and nothing. It's doesnt work as i want. What would be the problem?
Anybody can guide me and support me to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can split an array with the `.split()` method in python.

Comment: People are guessing what you want, but it isn't clear.  You have a list with 4 items, but describe  opening a file and printing lines.  What *exacty* is your input, what *exactly* is your desired output, and what *exactly* are you seeing that "doesnt work as i want"?  Please read how to post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I will try to edit my question. Thanks for your support and sorry for my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use readline() or read() to read the file.

```
with open(...) as f # You did well to use a with-statement!
    text = f.read()

mylist = text.split('\n')
```

Print by line

```
for item in mylist:
    print(item)

""" It prints:
wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CG - 0.990
wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CE1 - 0.916
wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CD2 - 0.963
wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C GLN 33 CD - 1.000 
"""
```

Parenthesis

```
print i  # nope
print(i) # yes
```

to split

```
result =to_split.split(mylist)
# result = ['wt_300_cont_6032', '-', '-', 'GLN', '33', 'C', 'HSD', '32', 'CG', '-', '0.990']
```

EDIT:

Following our conversation, we start directly with the input value, "input_list". If this works, we know the problem lies with the way we read the file.

Try to copy-paste and run it. It should work as you intend, it prints line by line.

```
input_list = ['wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CG - 0.990 ', 'wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CE1 - 0.916 ', 'wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CD2 - 0.963 ', 'wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C GLN 33 CD - 1.000 ']
for element in input_list:
    print(element)
```

Comment: Thanks but, I want to split each item, like in the above text. I mean, each item that is between ' ' .

Comment: I modified the result. in the "to split" section, it just removes empty spaces. You can then select in 'mylist' what you want and cast to any type you want int(mylist[4]). Note: to_split show how to split one line. You loop to do it on every lines, it's easy.

But your answer is vague. We are kinda guessing what you want.

Comment: Hi Florian, Thanks for your support. Sorry maybe my english is not well. But, I want to have an output as your section "Print by line", where says: "It prints". I'm trying with your script but for a strange reason, the result is the same list that input. Sorry, I'm new in python and I'am trying to research how solve it, really.

Comment: I have an idea. Let's forget about the file.read() and focus on how to print the data line by line. I'll edit my code... :)

Comment: Thanks Florian for your patient and to help me. Sorry for the ignorance and the bad moment. all the best for you!

Comment: No worries. Come back whenever you need help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the list is easy here:

```
for x in myList:
  print(x)
```

To write in file:

```
with open("filename.txt","rw") as f:
  for x in myList:
    f.write(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the result is the same. I don't understand why join, split and this way that you comment doesn't work. Would be because is "large" each item? For example: ' wt_300_cont_6032 - - GLN 33 C HSD 32 CG - 0.990 ' ?